# how to disable bone movement while keeping all transforms

Tags: animation, bones, transforms, constraints, inverse-kinematics

(ignore the crazy proportions in this scene I'm just experimenting) I'm trying to make the hand IK bone (square) stay exactly where it is between frames 705-726. I have a few constraints applied to it that helped with the rotation but I can't get the movement to be static. if you need to move the IK bone, turn off both the shrinkwrap constraint and limit rotations constraint.

[image]

if you need a closer look at the gif then open it in a new tab and zoom in

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11YQ6KP5Gwu6czC-DIgEwOwH-gLDCbygC?usp=sharing)

let me know if anything else is needed

Comment: still looking for a solution but i found a temporary solution. select the bone you need locked in place > Shift + S > Cursor to selected. then, do Shift + A > Empty > Plane Axes. and it should add right on the cursor. if it doesn't then do Shift + S again (with the empty selected) and do selection to cursor. click the bone you want to be locked again and give it a copy location constraint and make the target the empty. (youre also going to need to animate the influence value of the copy location constraint)

Comment: Add a copy transforms constraint, targeting an empty (or whatever.)  Constraint is at bottom of constraint stack.  Keyframe it at influence 0 at 704, 727, at influence 1.0 at 705, 726.